# Fuzzy Street Address Searches Using MySQL Fulltext (or sphinx?)

Tags: mysql, search, sphinx, full-text-search

I have a database table full of addresses from Google Maps geocode responses. Google abbreviates all directions (West -> W, East -> E, etc).

So if I enter an address like "100 West Pender Street" then the formatted address returned by Google Maps is "100 W Pender St" which I insert into my table.

Now if a user comes along and searches for that address, all of the following should match:

pender street
west pender street
100 pender
100 w pender
100 west pender

and they more or less do. the "w" in the table is ignored however because it falls below the minimum word length. addresses falling on east penner are given equal weighting in the search results (the "E" is also ignored).

What's the best way to handle this?

I suspect setting the minimum word length to 1 is a "bad thing".

I could do a search and replace against the known abbreviations (N, E, S, W, St, Ave, Dr, etc) in the google addresses and replace them with their expansions -- but there are some street names where this is not valid (some cities have single letter street names: J Street, etc...)

Also addresses like "123 160 St" are not searchable at all because the street number (123) and street name (160) both fall below the minimum word length.

Is MySQL FullText the right approach for this?
Does Sphinx offer something better?

Or is there another solution I haven't considered yet? Keep in mind that the user's search query will be matched not only against the property's address but also against other text columns such as the property name and description.

Comment: You can reduce mysql's fulltext min-word length with the `ft_min_word_length`, but lowering it down to 2 or 1 will increase the amount of "noise" results. Also, be careful with the abbreviations. In my city there is a "West Crescent", as that was some person's name, not a direction.

Comment: Why wouldn't create a new field with the direction (N,E,W,S) and then search with **field = 'S'** or if multiples searchs use ­­field IN ('S', 'N')

Comment: Marc - I am worried about the noise, especially if I have to set it to 1 to capture N, E, S, W. David - the addresses that come back from  the geocoder don't have the direction as a separate field so I would have to parse it out of the full text field which could be problematic for streets that are actually named "N" or "E" etc.