# Identifying duplicate records based on street addresses or maybe IP addresses?

Tags: mysql

I'm struggling with a seemingly easy mysql query.

I have a table called users with 3 columns and sample data:

```
user_id, ip_address,  street_address
1213,    10.0.0.5,    58 Howard Street
1522,    10.0.0.5,    58B Howard Street
1214,    10.0.0.5,    58 Howard Street E
2911,    10.0.0.5,    23 Fred Ave
5812,    10.2.4.1,    182 Billingsly Road
1921,    10.5.20.1,   33 Road Road
```

In the example, user_id's `1213`, `1522`, `1214` note duplicate records.

I think that I might need to use a subquery to identify the groups of street addresses with the unique `user_id`'s, but I'm not sure.

Doing something similar with the `ip_address` seems like a more efficient way to build the query, but again, I'm not sure.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  I don't suspect that my problem is all that unique and that identifying duplicates might be something someone else has found a great solution to.

Comment: but in user_id's `1213, 1522, 1214`, the street address are not exactly identical

Comment: You're right - I've clarified in my question.  There are multiple user_id's.

Comment: So ?? my question is "How you can say that  user_id's 1213, 1522, 1214 are duplicates when the street address is not exactly same ?

Comment: Thanks for the conversation here, I think that you're getting at the root of the problem I've been having.  Users are creating multiple accounts with similar street_addresses to so that I'll mail them a free product.  I'm trying to identify how often that's happening.

Comment: I understood your objective. In that case, you can only `GROUP BY ip_adress` and need some [pattern matching](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html) w.r.t street_address. In that case this query is not going to be seemingly easy :-).

Comment: Fuzzy matching on street_address is certainly not trivial

Comment: You're right - this is tougher than expected.  I was hoping that there was something between the ip_address and the street_address that would get me there.  What's the closest that I can get?  Some of these records do have identical street_addresses or at least groups of identical street_addresses for muliple user_id's.  I REALLY appreciate this.

Answer (score 0):

Try simple query using Group BY and HAVING clause like:

```
SELECT street_address, ip_address
FROM mytable
GROUP BY street_address, ip_address
HAVING COUNT(street_address, ip_address) > 1
```

Comment: This will not give any duplicate if you `GROUP BY street address` in that way. -1 downvote from me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958267/fuzzy-street-address-searches-using-mysql-fulltext-or-sphinx?rq=1